# Question about Lagrange Multiplier and Dot Product of Local Cauchy Problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I would have two questions from the book "Semilinear Schrödinger Equations" by Cazenave. The first is:

- Wouldn't the Lagrange multiplier span also over $-\Delta\varphi$?

The other question is:

- There is this part of taking the scalar product of the equation, but I completly can't follow how this is computed. Any idea?

[image]

[image]